# Understanding notation - strange use of the del operator

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, notation, vectors

I'm currently reading a paper with the following notation with the del operator which i have never encountered before:

[image: notation]

Does $\nabla _m$ just mean $\frac{\delta}{\delta \mathbf m} $ ? Furthermore, I have never seen $\nabla _m \nabla^T _m$ am I to interpret this as a matrix of partial derivatives?

Comment: What are $m$ and $V$?  Does $V$ depend on $m$?  And what is the awkward notation $x^{\i}$?

Comment: m and v are the mean and variance of a multivariate gaussian, $m^{\i}$ is the mean of a separate gaussian